# Difference in output printing a pre-initialized Java double vs. inline

Tags: java, string, floating-point

While upgrading a build from Java 1.6 to 1.7 our unit tests started failing because of a difference between how the 2 versions handle the printing of trailing zeros on doubles.

This can be reproduced with this example:

```
double preInit = 0.0010d;
System.out.println("pre-init: " + preInit);
System.out.println("  inline: " + 0.0010d);
```

Java 1.6 will output:

```
pre-init: 0.0010
  inline: 0.0010
```

Java 1.7 will output:

```
pre-init: 0.001
  inline: 0.0010
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why is the printing of an inline concatenation different than the same concatenation with a pre-initialized value?
2. What change between Java 1.6 and 1.7 is causing the difference in output from version to version?

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812504/java7-double-tostring-returns-0-005-java6-it-is-0-0050) should help.

Comment: @PM77-1 I would go as far as saying it is a duplicate. Is there any reason you didn't vote to close the question as duplicate?

Comment: I think @PM77-1 definitely answered part 2 of my question - there was a bug in Java that was fixed in 1.7.  I am still curious about part 1.

Comment: @PascalCuoq the fact that it has a related reason does not make the question a dupe. That question asks about a change in behavior between versions, this question notices the difference between behaviors in the same version. Interesting question!

Comment: @JoelBerger Ah, yes, you are right, the behavior of `System.out.println("pre-init: " + preInit);` on Java 1.7 is still puzzling. I vote for this question to stay open.

Comment: I ran your code using `JDK 1.7.0_17` (not the latest) and it showed `0.001` in both cases.  What Java 7 version are you using for compiling and running the code?

Comment: Additional description of the **same initial bug** is in [JDK-4511638 : Double.toString(double) sometimes produces incorrect results](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4511638).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part 1, it turns out the difference is in how the compiler optimizes the code.

The inline case decompiles to:

```
0:   getstatic       #16; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
3:   ldc     #22; //String   inline: 0.0010
5:   invokevirtual   #24; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
8:   return
```

Operation 3 indicates that it is already pushing the String constant "inline: 0.0010" to the stack.

Compare to the pre-initialized case:

```
0:   ldc2_w  #16; //double 0.0010d
3:   dstore_1
4:   getstatic       #18; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
7:   new     #24; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
10:  dup
11:  ldc     #26; //String pre-init:
13:  invokespecial   #28; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
16:  dload_1
17:  invokevirtual   #31; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(D)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
20:  invokevirtual   #35; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
23:  invokevirtual   #39; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
26:  return
```

Operation 11 pushes the label "pre-init: " to the stack and then the following operation use a StringBuilder to append the double value.

I think the Java bug that @PM77-1 mentioned was fixed in the Java Double class but not in the compiler.

Comment: Clearly the 1.7 compiler was compiled with Java 1.6. Should have bootstrapped :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping#Compilers

Comment: Which version of Java 7 compiler were you exploring?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_55"/Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)