# Java BigDecimal.doubleValue between Java 6 and Java 8

Tags: java

Case 1: In Java6 BigDecimal("0.0050000").doubleValue() returns **0.0050**, and in Java 8 return value is 0.005

Case 2: In Java6 BigDecimal("0.0250000").doubleValue() returns 0.025, and in Java 8 return value is 0.025

In case 1: Java 6 returns with extra trailing zero.. Any idea?? Also how to make Java 8 return the same output as Java 6

Comment: How do you print/visualize the value of the returned double?

Comment: doubleValue() returns a `double`, not a string. The two doubles in case 1 appear to be identical, aside from how you have printed / formatted them. See DecimalFormat

Comment: Please can you provide a complete example of a program that produces a different output for Java 6 and 8.

Comment: Complete code BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(0.0050000); System.out.println(decimal.doubleValue()); //Java 6 - 0.0050 and Java 8 - 0.005

Comment: I think, the issue could be in scale/precision.

Comment: Seems it was a bug. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812504/java7-double-tostring-returns-0-005-java6-it-is-0-0050

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is difference how System.out.println works in java6 and java 8.
Also we talk about doubles, BigDecimal is not a problem here. We can simplify this example to:

```
System.out.println(Double.toString(0.0050000));
```

Because println calls java.io.PrintStream#print(double) and then calls String.valueOf(d) you can check it in JDK.

But java.lang.Double#toString(double) looks different in JDK6 and JDK8:

```
return FloatingDecimal.toJavaFormatString(d);      //JDK 6
return new FloatingDecimal(d).toJavaFormatString();//JDK 8
```

I've found some JDK issues which has been fixed in java 7 (java 7 has same output like in java 8)

I think this issue maybe a cause:

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6935102

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7039369

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7032154